# Fivem remove job dependency. Im trying to fix so all players can search other players inventory without having a job

Tags: fivem

[I want remove the red box so u dont need a job to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGS5i.png)
Im new to scripting but im trying to learn maybe hard to understand but i want players to be able to search without them needing a job.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it can be like this

````
RegisterNetEvent("disc-inventoryhud:search2")
AddEventHandler("disc-inventoryhud:sealrch2",function()
        local plaver = ESX.GetPlayerData()
        local closestPlayer, closestDistance = ESX.Game.GetClosestPlayer()
        if closestPlayer ~= -1 and closestDistance <= 3.0 then
            local searchPlayerPed = GetPlayerPed(closestPlayer)
            ESX.TriggerServerCallback("disc-inventoryhud:getIdentifier",function(identifier)
                    secondarySearchInventory.owner = identifier
                    openInventory(secondarySearchInventory)
                end,
            GetPlayerServerId(closestPlayer)
           )
        end
    end
)```
````